# Preprocessing a String before creating JSON POJO

Tags: json, rest, jackson

I am creating a simple set of POJOs to hold incoming data for ISBN https://openlibrary.org/api/books

The REST API URL would look something like this:

https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:1234567890&format=json&jscmd=details

The responses of the REST call looks something like this (of course it's more complex than below example):

```
{
    "ISBN:1234567890": {
        "info_url": "https://openlibrary.org/books/OL23345657M/some_book_name",
        "bib_key": "ISBN:1234567890"
    }
}
```

The ISBN number changes based on the REST call made.
While trying to create a set of POJOs for the JSON structure, the POJO creator I used `http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/`
creates root class like ISBN1234567890.java. Which of course may not be correct.

Should I pre-process the JSON string to replace the string

```
{
    "ISBN:1234567890": {
```

with

```
{
    "BookInfo": {
```

first so that my root class remains BookInfo.java?

I am guessing there could be better solution approach to this problem rather than doing String manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You could just implement a throw-away wrapper class, something like:

```
public class Wrapper {
   public Map<String, BookInfo> info;
}
```

and peel out information you want from `info` property.